# passing data from didSelectRowAtIndexPath to another view controller ios7

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

i am trying to implement a slide menu, where when you select an option, it sends a variable value to a second view controller, which has a query from parse, which would get updated based on the selected value from the slide menu.

how do i pass a variable from didSelectRowAtIndexPath to another view controller

## menuViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *passVariable;
```

## menuViewController.m

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

UIViewController *newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
    _passVariable = @"FieldName";


[self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:ECRight animations:nil onComplete:^{
    CGRect frame = self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
    self.slidingViewController.topViewController = newTopViewController;
    self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
    [self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
}];

}
```

## SecondViewController.m

```
   NSString *vName = MenuViewViewController.passVariable;
```

tried the above, but the passVariable does not work in the secondViewController.m

Comment: Just to be clear, is this 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' method is in the MenuViewController? Also, is this 'newTopViewController' is the 'SecondViewController'?

Comment: yes its in the menu vie controller, and newTopViewController is not the secondviewcontroller

Answer (score 3):

You want to "push" objects to the next viewcontroller, not pull them from the previous viewController.

create a `@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *fieldName;` in your SecondViewController and use this:

```
SecondViewController *newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
newTopViewController.fieldName = @"FieldName";
```

Comment: do i have to declare an identifier, get the error "use of undeclared identifier"

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities as I see:

1) Try using `Singleton` approach: (if possible and necessary)

In menuViewController:

```
[Singleton sharedInstance].passVariable = @"yourValue here"
```

In secondViewController under `viewDidLoad`:

```
someProperty = [Singleton sharedInstance].passVariable;
```

2) Try by making a property in secondViewController:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * passVariable;
```

synthesize it:

```
@synthesize passVariable;
```

Now in menuViewController write like:

```
SecondViewController *newTopViewController = (SecondViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];

newTopViewController.passVariable = @"yourValue here";
```

Comment: on the second option, the passVariable does not show up as an option, keeps saying there is nothing called pass variable

Comment: cast to an appropriate controller instance

Comment: i added it in the .h file, but it still does not show as an option when i add the view controller name with dot syntax

Comment: i need to pass the variable from the menu view controller to the second view controller

Comment: make sure it is declared as a `property` and `synthesize` it as well.